# Добавление кнопки

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

```
    <html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script lang="javascript">
    function onKeyPress(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        val = $("input[name=name_of_input]").val();
        if (val == 1) document.location.href = '65.html';
        else if (val == 2) document.location.href = '43.html';
        else alert("Данный код в базе не хранится!");
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" name="name_of_input" onKeyPress="onKeyPress(event)"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Как еще добавить кнопку с текстом "проверить", и что бы она выполняла тоже действие, что и поле с клавишей энтер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем понимаю, что здесь Вы имели в виду,

> что и поле с клавишей энтер.

но, если имеется в виду кнопка, которая запускала бы проверку введённых пользователем данных, то лучше и создать такую кнопку, по щелчке на которой проверялось что именно ввёл пользователь и совершалась подгрузка нужной информации.

Answer (score 0):

Это не лучшее решение (так как я подстраиваюсь под Ваш нелучший код), но идея такая. Добавьте просто после своего поля такой HTML:

```
<button onclick="onKeyPress({keyCode: 13})">Проверить</button>
```